# How to remove EditText drawable padding?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I wasted the last hour trying to figure out how to get rid of this padding in a simple EditText:
[image]

All I want is to align the input with the rest of the content, just like the beautiful [design guide](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels) says.

The layout couldn't be simpler:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="com.actinarium.tiomantas.SetupChallengeFragment">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/new_challenge_name"/>

        <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:hint="@string/new_challenge_name_hint1"
                android:singleLine="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I tried setting padding on EditText to 0dp — the text shifted but the line remained as is. Strangely enough, I could not find ANY info on this issue, as if no one had noticed.

Comment: P.S. Something tells me that, like with anything else in Android, even for this trivial thing I'll have to make my own drawables... I just wonder why their native widgets don't follow their own design spec...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the line is a background image for the EditText so changing the padding won't affect it. If you want you can create a custom background drawable that has no padding.

Another hack you could do is add a negative margin to the EditText:

```
        <EditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_marginLeft="-4dp"
             android:hint="@string/new_challenge_name_hint1"
             android:singleLine="false"/>
```

Comment: Looked into the contacts app. Seems like the google devs followed this path and just accounted for the excessive 4 dips. I honestly thought there would be a nicer solution.
And in Fit they just left it as is

Comment: Yeah I agree, there should be nicer way of doing this.

Comment: Being perfectionist sucks :)
Now I'm worried this would break when they roll out a new design language :)

Comment: There should be some proper way to handle it, might they kept one attribute in the EditText

Answer (score 1):

Try giving "4dp" of padding for textView. So that it matches with editText padding.

Comment: I considered this. I am not completely sure though that this workaround won't break the UI in pre-Lollipop (and the last thing I'd want is having lots of version-specific XMLs)

Comment: I agree with you. But it's a small work around. I checked the result of adding padding in  my device with 4.4.2 and Emulator with 5.0 and it seems working fine.

Comment: Just looked into the contacts app on lollipop. Seems like the devs just accounted for that excessive 4dp and made margin smaller. Blimey...

Answer (score -1):

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.actinarium.tiomantas.SetupChallengeFragment">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="jhjkhkhkjkljlkjkljlkj"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:hint="hjhjhjkhjkhjkhkjhoiuyiyirehyiohj"
            android:singleLine="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you please explain why the changes that you have made will solve the problem - given that your solution increases the layout depth/complexity.